# Looking to create a menu that links to url

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a dropdown list on a page (not a menu dropdown) where the user picks a selection, presses go and it is directed to a website.
I can get the selection to go to the website without a submit button, but not with a submit button.
Do I need to add a submit condition to each line?

Thank you in advance :)

```
<select onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
<option value="#Make a selection">Make your selection</option>
<option value="URL1/#Selection 1">Selection 1</option>
<option value="URL2/#Selection 2">Selection 2</option>
<option value="URL3/#Selection 3">Selection 3</option>
</select><input type="button" value="Go" />
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a select options to add `<a href='yourURL.ext'>` to, since it might not work on all Browsers. I would create a custom dropdown with CSS3. There are tons of examples online. You could do like: `ButtonElement.onclick = ()=>{ location = SelectElement.value; }`

Answer (score 0):

Place the function on your `<button>` instead of the `<select>`.

```html
<select>
  <option value="#Make a selection">Make your selection</option>
  <option value="URL1/#Selection 1">Selection 1</option>
  <option value="URL2/#Selection 2">Selection 2</option>
  <option value="URL3/#Selection 3">Selection 3</option>
</select><input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:location.href = document.querySelector('select').options[document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex].value;"/>
```